# Toggling an AJAX Response in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I'm calling on the following AJAX function in order to pull and display specific categorical posts whenever a corresponding button is pushed:

```
<script>    
// Brochure AJAX

    function term_ajax_get(termID) {

        jQuery("#loading-animation").show();
        var ajaxurl = 'http://localhost/kskj-portal/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {"action": "load-filter2", term: termID },
                success: function(response) {
                    jQuery(".brochure-post-container").append(response);
                    jQuery("#loading-animation").hide();
                    return false;
                    }
            });
        }

</script>
```

The function is being called upon using the onclick attribute within the HTML in order to update the function's input (termID) dynamically:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product):
    // setup the product/cateogory ID
    $product_name = $product->name;
    $product_id= $product->term_id;
    $product_slug = $product->slug;

    ?>


    <div class="product-container OFF" onclick="term_ajax_get(<?php echo $product->term_id; ?>)">
```

Is there a way where I can toggle the specific post being displayed? Basically if a button is pushed, its corresponding posts are displayed. If the button is pushed again, the posts are hidden. If one button is pushed, and then another button is pushed, both categories posts display at the same time until one of the buttons is pressed again.

Right now every time a button is being pushed it appends that category's post onto the page. I need to get the category onto the page when pushed, but I don't know how to remove it when its corresponding button is pushed again, or how to add other categories when both buttons are selected.

Comment: This is a bit broad, so I'll be kind of general here... In order for the same button to perform both actions, you'd need to examine some kind of condition in the click handler before performing the action. In your case that condition is, "Is the content already on the page?" Detect that by looking for some expected element that would only be there if it was returned by the previous button click. If that content is there, remove it. If it isn't, fetch and insert it. (You can further improve by also detecting if the content is *hidden* and show/hide it, so it's only fetched once.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few solutions. In the example below, you could just use `data` attribute of the element, and depending on your needs, load fresh data via ajax each time, or switch visibility of already existing elements (to prevent connections).

Put each ajax response into an unique element (in the example below, each element has its unique `data-term-id` attribute), so that you can easily check presence of an element later on.

PHP:

```
<div class="product-container OFF" data-term="<?php echo $product->term_id; ?>">blah</div>
```

Js script:

```
function term_ajax_get(termID) 
{
    $("#loading-animation").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/kskj-portal/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: 
        {
            action: "load-filter2", 
            term: termID 
        },
        success: function(response) 
        {
            $(".brochure-post-container").append('<div data-term-id="'+termID+'">'+response+'</div>');
            return $("#loading-animation").hide();
        }
    });
}

$(".product-container").click(function()
{
    var termID = $(this).data("term");
    if(!$("[data-term-id='" + termID + "']").length)
    {
        return term_ajax_get(termID);
    }
    //OPTION 1.: TO PREVENT UNNECESSARY CONNECTIONS, SWITCH VISIBILITY OF THE ELEMENT IF ALREADY EXIST:
    $("[data-term-id='" + termID + "']").toggle();

    //OPTION 2.: USE IF YOU NEED TO SHOW FRESH DATA EACH TIME:
    //$("[data-term-id='" + termID + "']").remove();
});
```

Comment: **Christopher Lis**, let me know whether or not this worked for you